# Copy a script to a list of sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I am going to implement to some 100 is sheets. The script is needed to copy over new rows from all sheets into a centralized sheet. We are currently using import range but it seems to break all the time due to the volume of sheets that are being imported from.

My question is: Is there a way to "Copy" over my script to the 100 sheets without having to manually go one by one and Tools > Script Editor > Paste > Save > Close and repeat ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintaining enabled APIs in Container-bound Script for a Google Sheet Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604982/maintaining-enabled-apis-in-container-bound-script-for-a-google-sheet-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by a sheet you mean spreadsheet then you can use one script to access all the other sheets as long as you have permission to access them.  If you have access and want to copy script to all of the them then you can use Apps Script API to copy all of the scripts but you will still need to authenticate every copy.  You could also just make copies of the spreadsheet and you are still stuck with authenication.